# (Java) if statement not evaluating equality between int values

Tags: java

```
int count = charFreq.get(guessChar);
int matchedChars = updatedCharFreq.get('_');
                
if (updatedKeyVals.contains('_')) {
                    
    if (count == matchedChars) {
        ;
    }
                    
    if (count < matchedChars) {
        ;
    }
                    
    else {
        count = count - matchedChars;
    }
```

Method works if count < matchedChars, and also the else statement. It just skips past the if equality statement. I have been trying to figure it out, but just can't seem to.

Comment: The code looks correct. You should check if the two values that are being compared are actually what you assume they are.

Comment: You missed an `else` here -- `if (count < matchedChars) {`

Comment: @f1sh used the debugger, and both the values are same. Tried typecasting both the values to int, since they're from a <Character, Integer> ArrayList, but that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch tried it, didn't work :(

Comment: I have pointed out the obvious bug. Now it is time for you to read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71094585/java-if-statement-not-evaluating-equality-between-int-values#comment125675330_71094585), you neglected to chain the first `if` with an `else`.

I suggest accounting for all cases explicitly plus an extra final case that should never be reached. The extra check is for defensive programming, to guard against editing errors.

```
if (count == matchedChars) {
    // No code needed here.
} else if (count < matchedChars) {
    // No code needed here.
} else if (count > matchedChars) {
    count = count - matchedChars;
} else {
    throw new IllegalStateException( … ) ; // Should never reach this point. 
}
```

It seems you only care about the case where the first number is bigger than the second. So we could shorten this code.

```
if (count > matchedChars) {
    count = count - matchedChars;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the static method [`Integer.compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int,int)). To quote the Javadoc:

> Returns: the value 0 if x == y; a value less than 0 if x < y; and a value greater than 0 if x > y

```
if( Integer.compare( count , matchedChars ) > 0 ) {
    count = count - matchedChars;
}
```

Comment: Yikes. https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/12/21/creating-a-good-feedback-loop-between-ops-and-devs-using-documentation/